# image view not show when use on nine patch image in android

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview

I am using nine patch image (shadow_15347) as a background for shadow and above it i am using image view with background or src of my logo png. my nine patch image show but my logo png not show when it run on emulator. while in design view of activity it shows properly please tell me where i am wrong thanks in advance.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_15347"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in imageview why are using android:background tag to set your image, you could src tag and check.

Comment: i try this but there is nothing happened